# Random errors while downloading files from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using Sharepoint 2007 to host Excel 2007 files generated by my App, so that internal clients can download them. However, I sometimes (and it seems random) the bigger files fail to download (Internet Explorer and Firefox claim the download was successful, but the size of the file is smaller than expected and it is not usable). The files in Sharepoint are fine, because sometimes they download ok (so after trying a few times I can successfully download any file).

Any ideas what causes it and if there are any workarounds available?

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about the connection files that SharePoint uses? Can you post an image of this showing the steps you took?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post a snippet showing what's happening in code? There are numerous issues in file downloading capabilities of IIS because the whole process depends on multiple factors network failures etc

Please refer [link text](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406)